# jquery-ui : ThemeRoller > How to apply a specified theme?

Tags: jquery-ui

i use the **ThemeRoller** from jquery UI, as follow :

```
     HTML: <div id="switcher"></div>

     jQuery: $('#switcher').themeswitcher({ .... });
```

How to apply a specified theme (for example : "Start") when i click on a input button ?

---

In fact, I did not find solution to my problem, although I took time to do it!

In other words here is my problem: i would like to offer the user **only 3 themes** for the UI, e.g. "Smoothness, Start and Flick". To change and choose the next theme, the user simply presses an "input button".

How to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the solution given here:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/using_multiple_jquery_ui_themes_on_a_single_page/

HTH